# HtmlUnit and XPath fail to retrieve HTML element

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to get an input element from this web:

https://www.milanuncios.com/textos-del-anuncio/?demandax=n&c=131&idlocalidad=8&p=almeria&x=27&y=0

The input itself is:

```
<input class="inputs campoGrande" name="marca" value="" maxlength="120" size="12" id="marca" tabindex="1" type="text">
```

I have tried different approaches but all I always get is a "null" reference:

```
HtmlInput inputZona = (HtmlInput) currentPage.getElementById("marca");
HtmlInput inputZona = (HtmlInput) currentPage.getFirstByXPath("//input[@name='marca']");
```

Also tried JSoup with same results :-(

Both, HTMLUnit and XPAth fail to get the item.

What is going on with this?

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: Note that that page is XHTML, so you could try to either declare that as the default namespace or wildcard XPath e.g. //*:input

Comment: @chrisis, thanks. I have managed to do it by using absolute paths with XPath (/html/body/div/form...). Don't really understand why this is the only input item that was not correctly processed by HTMLUnit though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works here with the latest version of HtmlUnit (2.28-SNAPSHOT).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.milanuncios.com/textos-del-anuncio/?demandax=n&c=131&idlocalidad=8&p=almeria&x=27&y=0");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());

        HtmlInput inputZona = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("marca");
        System.out.println(inputZona.asXml());
    }
```